# Extending side margins for Title section in IEEEtrans document class

Tags: margins, titles, ieeetran, width, ieee-style

How can one extend the side margins only for the title section of IEEEtrans (conference) document class? I need to have more words fitting in each line for the "title only".

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}

\title{I want to make a title that its length is adjustable and that can span into maximum two lines instead of three now} 

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place the title inside a `\parbox` of the desired length (for example, `\textwidth+2cm`), which will go inside a `\makebox` (to full TeX into thinking the width has not exceeded `\linewidth`); something like this:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}

\author{The author}
\title{\makebox[\linewidth]{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth+2cm\relax}{\centering I want to make a title that its length is adjustable and that can span into maximum two lines instead of three now}}}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

I, however, would suggest you not to do this; it looks ugly to have a title with so narrow margins.

Comment: I completely agree with you. I tried it in two-lines and realized I'd better stick with three-lines instead; it would look better!